# Scala BigDecimal how to display more decimals?

Tags: scala, bigdecimal, digits, pi, decimal

First of all, I am aware that there is a similar topic regarding the division of 1 by 3. However, my code is quite different and I don't know how to apply the information given there to my situation. I would appreciate any and all help.

I made a Pi calculator in Scala and at the end of the code I print the result. However, I want to have a much larger number of decimals and I don't know how to achieve that. My current output is :

```
Expected decimals: 34
3.141592653589793238462643383279500
```

Here's the code:

```
package theBrain
object Calculator 
{
def main(args: Array[String]) 
{

var i = 100
var j = 100
var lastValueOnFirstLine = j+i
var array = new Array [BigDecimal] (0)

var counter = i-1

for (d <- j to lastValueOnFirstLine by 1)
{
  var almostPi = BigDecimal(0)
  var pi = BigDecimal(0)

  for (b <- 0 to d by 1)
  {
      var partialAnswer = (if (b%2 != 0) {-1} else {1} )/((BigDecimal(2)*BigDecimal(b))+BigDecimal(1))
      almostPi = partialAnswer + almostPi

  }
  pi = 4*almostPi
 array = array:+pi
}

for (z <- counter to 0 by -1){
var array2 = new Array [BigDecimal] (0)
var length = array.length -2
for (a <- 0 to length by 1){

var result = (array(a)+array(a+1))/2
array2 = array2:+result
}
array = array2
counter -= 1
}

for (element <- array) {
println("Expected decimals: " + element.precision)
println(element)
}

}
}
```

Comment: I don't get it. You expect 34 digits and you get 34 digits. So where's the problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to supply a different `java.math.MathContext` when you create your instances of `BigDecimal`. Note that this effects the precision of the calculation, not only how many decimals are printed on output. This is quite different from the mere formatting of numbers.

```
scala> BigDecimal(1) / 3
res0: scala.math.BigDecimal = 0.3333333333333333333333333333333333

scala> res0.precision
res1: Int = 34

scala> BigDecimal(1, new java.math.MathContext(50)) / 3
res2: scala.math.BigDecimal = 0.33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333

scala> res2.precision
res3: Int = 50
```